# Scikit inpainting returning error: Input arrays have to be the same shape

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I have the following two images. One is the original, and the other is the mask. I am attempting to use inpainting to REMOVE everything but the drawn writing on the page.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Zxs.jpg)
[Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhHyz.png)

I am using the following code to do this:

```
import cv2
from skimage.restoration import inpaint

image_orig = cv2.imread('R.jpg')
# Create mask with six block defect regions
mask = cv2.imread('InkedR.jpg')

image_result = inpaint.inpaint_biharmonic(image_orig, mask, channel_axis=-1)
```

I am returned the following error:

`ValueError: Input arrays have to be the same shape`

I have confirmed that both the image and the mask are the same shape by using:
`image_orig. shape == mask.shape`
and do not know what is causing this error.

I have tried to use different images, and also convert the images to black and white with no help.

Comment: Try reading both images as grayscale or convert them to grayscale.

Comment: The docs say for the mask "Unknown pixels have to be represented with 1, known pixels - with 0." So it needs to be dtype=bool.  See https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.restoration.html?highlight=biharmonic#skimage.restoration.inpaint_biharmonic and the example at https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/filters/plot_inpaint.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-filters-plot-inpaint-py where they start with "mask = np.zeros(image_orig.shape[:-1], **dtype=bool**)"

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the function with a binary mask which can be achieved by extracting the mask from the provided images and then converting it to the binary scale.

**Solution:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.restoration import inpaint_biharmonic

# Load Images
Original_Image = cv2.imread("2.png")
Color_Mask = cv2.imread("1.jpg")

# Subtract Mask
Sub_Mask = np.array(Color_Mask.astype(float)-Original_Image.astype(float))
Sub_Mask = np.float32(Sub_Mask/255).astype('uint8')

# Binary Mask
Mask = cv2.cvtColor(Sub_Mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply Inpaint Biharmonic Function
Restored_Image = inpaint_biharmonic(Original_Image, Mask, channel_axis=-1)

# Display Images
cv2.imshow("Display - Mask", Mask)
cv2.imshow("Display - Restored Image", Restored_Image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Output:**

[Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co5FB.jpg) [Restored Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIJse.jpg)